# Use cases for Cache-Control: min-fresh

Tags: http, caching, http-headers

A valid Cache-Control directive is `min-fresh=<seconds>`, which means "the client wants a response that will still be fresh for at least the specified number of seconds" ([ref](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.1.3)).

I can't think of or find online a use case or practical implementation of this. It seems to require the server to time-travel or lock a resource against edits for `<seconds>`. Does anyone have example use cases or implementations?